# How to prove that there exists a specific path?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Let G(V,E) be an **undirected** graph.
if there exists a vertex called `u` that its degree is **not even** then it is connected to **another** vertex `v` that its degree is also **not even**.

I tried to prove this by contradiction but reached a closed end, may I get help with this?

**Note: The sentence says there exists one so I can't choose v and u specifically.**

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Let $V=\{1,2,3,4\}, E=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ and $u=1, v=3$.

Comment: @curlycharcoal you can't choose u or v, I need to prove there exists at least one...

Comment: So in your example u=1 v=2 proves it, or v=1 u=2 or v=3 u=4...

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you reword the question to something like *“there exists a vertex v...”* to make that clear?

Comment: corrected that, thanks for you both!

Comment: can I get at least a hint?

Comment: As stated, the claim is false. There exist graphs where all vertices have even degree.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But we are given a vertex $u$ of odd degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that "$u$ is connected to $v$" means that there is a path from $u$ to $v$.  Let $C$ be the component of $G$ containing $u$, that is the largest connected subgraph of $G$ containing $u$.  Note that the vertices $C$, other than $u$ itself, are precisely of those vertices $v$ such that there is a path from $u$ to $v$.

If the theorem is false, then $C$ is a graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree.  What lemma have you learned that shows this is impossible?

Comment: Regarding the lemma they didn't name/prove it just gave it to us. But I'm allowed to use it

Comment: @Daniel98 It's usually called the "handshaking lemma."  At a cocktail party, the number of people who have shaken hands an odd number of times must be even.

Comment: @Daniel98 I only used one letter, $C$, that you didn't use already.

Comment: Ok I get it now, but how could you choose C if you don't know who is u

Comment: @Daniel98 Every vertex lies in a component.  The component comprises that vertex and all the vertices reachable from it, together with all the edges joining them.